# how to validate combobox in flex before save has to select some item in a combobox?

Tags: apache-flex

How can I validate there's a selected item in a ComboBox before saving? If there's no selected item, how can I set focus on the ComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set focus to the comboBox:

```
focusManager.setFocus(myComboBox);
```

Answer (score 1):

As part of your save procedure, just check to make sure something is selected.  Something like this:

```
if(myComboBox.selectedIndex >-1){
  Alert.show('You must select an item in myComboBox','Error');
  return;
}
// perform other save operations
```

Comment: @Hari kanna As someone else said, you can use the focusManager to set focus on the ComboBox.